# meaning of "knocking back on"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm reading Lawrence Block's memoir, in which he mentions about volunteer travel opportunities offered by Earthwatch. He explains that for a not-too-steep fee, one might join an expedition in aid of some environmental goal, such as to save the endangered red pandas. Then he says:

> Lynne and I weren't sufficiently high-minded to sign up for one of their trips. We’d be eager to inoculate villagers in the Cameroun against dengue fever instead of, say, **knocking back on** a cruise of the South Pacific.

What does "knocking back on a cruise" mean here? I tried to look up the dictionary for "knock", "knock back", or "knock back on". But their definitions don't seem to fit this context.

Answer (score 4):

This is the only definition that makes sense to me:

> To drink an alcoholic beverage swiftly or often. [(Wiktionary)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/knock_back)

It's usually transitive, as in "knock back a few drinks" so I'm a little surprised by the phrasing here.  Still, I think the author is trying to describe a luxury activity they'd be more willing to do: knocking back a few drinks on a cruise ship.

My only other guess would be that they meant something like "kicking back":

> *(especially North American English)* to relax Kick back and enjoy the summer.
>   [(Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/learner/kick-back)

That would make sense in context, too.  The meaning would be similar: relaxing on a cruise ship.

But he's a professional writer, and it's probably best to assume he used the phrase he intended, so I'm going with "knock back (a few drinks)".